# Django - How to remember values and show errors in form validation?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I'm not getting how to remember values and show errors in form validation.

Here is my code:

template.html:

```
<form method="post" action="/submeter/anuncio/">{% csrf_token %}
    {{form_main.as_p}}
    {{form_bicyclead.as_p}}
    {{form_bicycleadcategory.as_p}}
    {{form_bicycleaditemkindandpropertyvalueform.as_p}}
    <input type="hidden" name="section" value="5" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

views.py:

```
def submit_ad_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':      
        model_main = Main()
        model_main.section = Section.objects.get(pk=request.POST['section'])
        model_main.user = request.user

        model_bicyclead = BicycleAd()
        model_bicyclead.bicycleadtype = BicycleAdType.objects.get(pk=2)
        model_bicyclead.bicycleaditemkind = BicycleAdItemKind.objects.get(pk=4)
        model_bicyclead.bicycleadcondition = BicycleAdCondition.objects.get(pk=2)
        model_bicyclead.city = GeonamesLocal.objects.get(pk=4803854)


        form_main = MainForm(request.POST, instance = model_main)
        form_bicyclead = BicycleAdForm(request.POST, instance = model_bicyclead)
        form_bicycleadcategory = BicycleAdCategoryForm(request.POST)

        if form_main.is_valid() and form_bicyclead.is_valid() and form_bicycleadcategory.is_valid():
            main_f = form_main.save()

            bicyclead_f = form_bicyclead.save(commit=False)
            bicyclead_f.main = main_f
            bicyclead_f.save()

            bicycleadcategory_f = form_bicycleadcategory.save(commit=False, rel_obj=model_bicyclead)


            resultado = 'valid'
        else:
            resultado = 'n_valid'

        return render_to_response('app_p/submit_ad.html', {'form_main': form_main, 'form_bicyclead': form_bicyclead, 'form_bicycleadcategory': form_bicycleadcategory, 'form_bicycleaditemkindandpropertyvalueform': form_bicycleaditemkindandpropertyvalueform}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form_main = MainForm()
        form_bicyclead = BicycleAdForm()
        form_bicycleadcategory = BicycleAdCategoryForm()
        form_bicycleaditemkindandpropertyvalueform = BicycleAdItemKindAndPropertyValueForm()

        return render_to_response('app_p/submit_ad.html', {'form_main': form_main, 'form_bicyclead': form_bicyclead, 'form_bicycleadcategory': form_bicycleadcategory, 'form_bicycleaditemkindandpropertyvalueform': form_bicycleaditemkindandpropertyvalueform}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Some clues on what is wrong in this template and view to not getting the errors and not remember the values for the form?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems with your code, first in the `if` you use to validate your forms, when the first form returns `False` the rest won't be validated.

Second, you are recreating the forms when one of them is invalid and you are not passing them any values, so they end up empty and withou validation information.

Comment: I've updated the code. What variables can I pass to the forms?

Comment: Hi. Yes, the same result. No errors and no data re-population.

Comment: No errors on all the forms? If your main form is invalid the others won't run their validate and won't have any errors added.

Comment: No errors at all. The tag "{{form_main.as_p}}" will show automatically the errors?

Comment: Hi André, I guess you solved the problem, just curious, what was it?